# Random avatar generator

Tags: php, random, avatar-generation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [what is the algorithm used to generate those little gravatar identicon images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images)

StackOverflow seems to have nice, randomly generated avatars for default users. How do I do that (preferably with PHP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: It doesn't ask what they use, it's asking how *he* could create one.

Comment: And an excellent answer to that is to use gravatar :)

Comment: @Jasie :-)

@George Stocker, The question was how stackoverflow did it, and how they can as well. The answer of gravatar answers both questions ;-)

Comment: This takes link only answers to a whole new level

Answer (score 1):

Gravatar: http://en.gravatar.com/

Here is a link to their reference php implementation: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/php